# 1004 error "Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Tags: vba, excel, date

My goal: make Excel save a copy of the workbook in a folder different from the original folder where the workbook is and as well with a timestamp.

This code runs correctly:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "  _
  (" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ").xlsm")
End Sub
```

But this code doesn't run at all. I get Error 1004 every time I close the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (ThisWorkbook.Name & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"))
End Sub
```

The message I get when trying to close the workbook with the second code: http://prntscr.com/8iiyyd

Comment: File names cannot contain colons. Replace it with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the colon that prevents Windows from saving the file, plus the extension will be strange with the timestamp added like this. 
Your code would produce the following filename: 
**Try.xlsm2015-09-22 15:37**

You will also need to supply your folder location.

Maybe you can try this:

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "c:\folder\" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xl", Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ".xl")

You can of course specify your own folder.

If you want to put it in a subfolder, relative to the current file location, then use this:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Thisworkbook.Path & "\subfolder\" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xl", Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ".xl")
```

You can of course specify your own subfolder

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue. I didn't want to use Replace for the second code (I want to achieve the same thing with another code).

Here is the repaired code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\Korisnik\Box Sync\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hhmm") & ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

It all works now,
Many thanks